# Is there a way to set the default font-family for the entire react app without styled-component?

Tags: reactjs, themes

I was searching for a way to set the default font-family for the entire react app but all results/packages point to react native instead. For react is there a way to default a global font setting without specifying font-family in every css? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly this should do:

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);

body {
   font-family: 'Open Sans',serif;
}
```

Comment: how about the many different components on different routed page? is there a way to set it once and for all as the default of the entire app?

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html#limited-style-inheritance

Comment: So, to your question, no, not without a styled component