# How to set a global font family in react js?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to set one font family for all text in react like this :

index.css file :

```
:root {
    font-family: 'Vazir', sans-serif !important;
}
```

But it doesn't apply and I have to apply `font-family: 'Vazir', sans-serif !important;` to every component css file .

How can I code font family once and it applies to every component text or How can I set a global font family style that applies to all text rendered in react js ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to set the default font-family for the entire react app without styled-component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59306327/is-there-a-way-to-set-the-default-font-family-for-the-entire-react-app-without-s)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to effect the font of all text on all pages. Simply replace `:root` with `*`. The * selector effects everything on the given page.

Make sure to import your css file into every react page you want it to take effect on.

Comment: No prob. Glad I could help

Comment: Just one thought, instead of adding index.css file into every react page,
we should import & add index.css file in our index.js file as it is starting point of react app, so it is always going to run.

Make sure index.css is located in same directory like that of index.js.

Answer (score 7):

You should be fine adding your font-family to

```
body, html { 
  font-family: 'Vazir', sans-serif;
}
```

There are a few things to look out for when doing this in react:

- Are you importing your CSS file into the root component? `<App/>`
- Are you using a css-loader in your webpack configuration?
- Are you setting your @font-family before trying to use it?
- Or have you imported your font from a link="rel"?

Answer (score 0):

Just one thought, instead of adding `index.css` file into every react page,
we should import & add `index.css` file in our `index.js` file as it is starting point of react app, so it is always going to run.

Make sure `index.css` is located in same directory like that of `index.js`.